# Angular 2 - Receiving TSLint errors in my node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, webpack

I just installed this [angular2-material-datepicker](https://github.com/koleary94/Angular-2-Datepicker) using NPM. It's installed in my `node_modules` folder, however I receive tslint errors which I shouldn't be getting.

```
ERROR in ./~/angular2-material-datepicker/index.ts
[1, 15]: ' should be "
```

However in my `tsconfig.json` I clearly state that my `node_modules` folder should be excluded.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2016", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },

  "include": [
    "client/**/*"
  ],

  "exclude": [ "node_modules", "dist" ]
}
```

I confirmed that the module is located in my `node_module` folder. This is the first module which gives me these errors.

Any idea for possible solutions?

thanks!

Comment: not sure if this is the issue.. but I think it should be     `"lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],`

Comment: @suraj `"lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ]`, `"lib": [ "es2016", "dom" ]`, and `"lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ]` are all valid along with many others.

Comment: Look for the ignore option on TSLINT website, I don't have it handy right now but that's what you need to use

Comment: @AluanHaddad solved the issue, it had to exclude it under webpack aswell

Comment: Oh I forget that y'all run everything through webpack even linters

Comment: You probably should post an answer to your own question so that others can benefit.

Comment: @AluanHaddad done :) thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue was with webpack.

I had to exclude `node_modules` over there aswell.

So in `/config/base.js` I excluded it from the rules like this.

```
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
              enforce: 'pre',
              test: /\.ts$/,
              loader: 'tslint-loader',
              options: {
                  emitErrors: true,
                  failOnHint: true
              },
              exclude: /node_modules/
          },
```